# how to scanf two chars in a row - assembly %c %c

Tags: assembly, x86

I get trouble with scanf of two chars- 
(%c,%c)
I try-

```
subl    $4,     %esp        
pushl   %esp                
pushl   "%c %c"         
call    scanf               
leal    (%esp),  %ebx       
movzbl  (%ebx),  %ebx
```

this- will - scan 2 chars in EBX?

i need to get the two of them to one register? 
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, it won't. It may cause some bad things due to lack of arguments for `scanf()`.

Try this:

```
subl    $4,      %esp # allocate a buffer
leal    1(%esp), %ebx
pushl   %ebx          # where to store the second character
decl    %ebx
pushl   %ebx          # where to store the first character
pushl   $str1
call    scanf
add     $12,     %esp # discard the arguments
movzwl  (%esp),  %ebx
addl    $4,      %esp # discard the buffer

# put this where won't be executed
str1: .asciz "%c %c"
```

This program will store the first character to the least significant byte, and the second character to the second least significant byte.

[demo](https://ideone.com/pNCqxa)